# Log4j 2 different log File for each Thread

Tags: logging, concurrency, routes, log4j2

I m using log4j 2 and i have the need to write different log files based on the value of a particular key stored in ThreadContext Map. Each Thread sets the key to a particular value (that could be repeated...).
This is the log4j2.xml

```
<Configuration status="warn">
<Appenders>
    <Routing name="Routing">
        <Routes pattern="$${ctx:KEY}">              
            <Route>
                <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:KEY}" fileName="logs/${ctx:KEY}.log"
                    filePattern="logs/${date:yyyy-MM}/${ctx:KEY}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
                    <PatternLayout>
                        <pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%t] %p %c{3} - %m%n</pattern>
                    </PatternLayout>
                    <Policies>
                        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6"
                            modulate="true" />
                        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
                    </Policies>
                </RollingFile>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </Routing>
    <Async name="Async">
        <AppenderRef ref="Routing" />
    </Async>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Async" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This is the Main class:

```
public class TestClass {

public static void main (String[] args){
    /**FILTER OPERATION*/

    CorrelationBag corr = new CorrelationBag();
    corr.setID("AD65MASDAD654DF5SDF235SFD651SDFSDF321DSF");
    corr.setUsername("Username");       


    for (int i= 0; i<6; i++){           
        (new Thread(new MyService(i))).start();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is finally the Thread Implementation:

```
public class MyService extends ServiceBase implements Runnable {
int counter;
public MyService (){}

public MyService (int counter){
    this.counter = counter;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    ThreadContext.put("KEY", Thread.currentThread().getID());
    String param1 = "param1";
    String param2 = "param2";
    String param3 = "param3";
    String param4 = "param4";
    String param5 = "param5";
        info("WITH MARKER AND HEADERS,{},{}{},{},{}",param1,param2,param3,param4,param5);       
    ThreadContext.remove("threadName");

    }
}
```

With this code Log4j creates just 1 log file related to just 1 thread ID.

If i run the code in debug mode, executing every single instruction step by step... log4j creates 6 files as i wanted. I guess it could be a concurrency issue in my code.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your current code has the possibility that each thread will be created, start and finish before the next thread is created, so the thread object may get reused. I would suggest you change your code to do:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[6];

for (int i= 0; i < 6; i++) {           
    threads[i] = new Thread(new MyService(i));
}
for (int i= 0; i < 6; i++){           
    threads[i].start();
}
```

Also, you are added "KEY" to the thread context but removing "threadName". That is going to cause problems. You example above also doesn't actually have a logger call. I am assuming it should be logger.info, not just info.